# Selenium Webdriver - Java - selecting a link stored in a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, string, selenium-webdriver, href

I'm working in a for loop, picking up on a value in the far left column of a table and from there want to select the corresponding link in the far right column.  The far right column contains 3 links.

The link 'names' are not unique and the `href` attributes are variable.

I have used the command;

`String Amend = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[" + v + "]/td[9]/a[1]")).getAttribute("href");`

...to store the href attribute to the variable Amend and want to then select the link by the variable name, is this possible?

I have tried `Amend.click();` and also `driver.findElement(etc.......).click;`, but Eclipse has flagged these as being incorrect.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: post exception here. i beleive your issue is XPath expression

Answer (score 1):

**Amend.click()** won't work because it's just a string.

If you want to open the link you should navigate to url by **driver.navigate().gotourl(Amend)**